# Why can't I declare a nested class that is a subclass of a sealed class?

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors

The [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) states:

> A sealed class can have subclasses, but all of them must be declared in the same file as the sealed class itself. (Before Kotlin 1.1, the rules were even more strict: classes had to be nested inside the declaration of the sealed class).

Admittedly, this is worded as a necessary but not sufficient condition, but it does imply (by lack of anything contrary) that I can declare a subclass of a sealed class anywhere in the same file.

Given that the following code compiles:

```kotlin
//class Jungle {
    sealed class Animal
    class Tiger : Animal()
//}
```

why does the following not compile:

```kotlin
class Jungle {
    sealed class Animal
    class Tiger : Animal()
}
```

The second snippet gives the following errors with Intellij Kotlin plugin version `1.3.72-release-IJ2020.1-5`:

```
Error:(3, 20) Kotlin: Cannot access '<init>': it is private in 'Animal'
Error:(3, 20) Kotlin: This type is sealed, so it can be inherited by only its own nested classes or objects
```

In fact, the second error message here seems to directly contradict the documentation.

Comment: Looks like there's a bug report for it that never gained any traction: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13495) for it that also notes the misleading diagnostic message. But it seems the conversation around it died down.

Also, this [Sealed class inheritance proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/sealed-class-inheritance.md#open-questions) from 4 years ago leaves the matter of sub-classing a nested sealed class by a class on the same level as an open question